# Netrw-R Renaming multiple Files with vim

Tags: substitute, netrw, filesystem, multiple-files

After going through the renaming guides from the doc folder in vim I found a way to replace text with the input `:%s/frompattern/topattern/g`.
Reaching the renaming files with the file browser tutorial/guide I managed to learn the MR and R method stated in the netrw-R help file.

Then I tried to use the text replacing method on multiple files like so:

```
:set ma
:%s/frompattern/topattern/g
```

All the files changed after backspacing the `:` requested from the notification

```
"Press Enter or Type Command To Continue".
```

All files changed unfortunately those changes have only been made inside vim , no files have been altered.

Is there a way to apply the changes after renaming them that way or is that input strictly for text inside a file/document ?

Trying to exit vim through `:x` assuming it would apply changes gives me:

```
E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)
Press Enter or Type Command To Continue
```

Trying to exit with `:x!` gives me:

```
"/home/user/VimLearning/"
E502: "/home/user/VimLearning/" is a directory
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I can only exit with `:qa!`

[This post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21146/is-it-possible-to-edit-the-name-of-files-by-opening-their-root-folder-on-vim) explains the same technique as the NetRw-R help file but better in my opinion.

But the question remains as to renaming multiple files via `:%s/frompattern/topattern/g` and applying those changes. Would it be possible ?

Thanks for all the answers , I am really enjoying learning Vim and the QMV suggestion that was posted here. In the NetRw-R help file there is this info:

The g:netrw_rename_cmd variable is used to implement remote renaming. By default its value is:

```
ssh HOSTNAME mv
```

One may rename a block of files and directories by selecting them with V (linewise-visual) when using thin style.

The latter is what I am interested in. Renaming a block of files and directories. There are no examples. Would anyone be kind enough to point me towards one ? Or has that feature been removed or it is only for the renaming of remote files and folders as the text above it would mention ? Would that work the same as QMV ? Thank you guys , this community has been very helpful.

Comment: I would use external tools like `vidir`, `qmv` and the such for that. Or `vifm` file manager.

Comment: Welcome to Vi&Vim SE....and to Vim!  :)

Comment: As I pointed out in the answer, netrw can't do mass renames as qmv or emacs dired do.

Answer (score 1):

Netrw doesn't support file renames based on buffer changes (the way emacs dired does it).

There are external tools like `vidir` and `qmv` that runs vim (to be precise `EDITOR`) with directory contents where you can change filenames to be renamed "en masse".

It looks like this:

[image]

PS, you can also run it from within vim using built-in terminal: `:term vidir`

Comment: Note that `qmv` is part of the package known as [renameutils](http://www.nongnu.org/renameutils/). These are some excellent tools. Use `qmv` and `qcp` for bulk operations. Also check out `icp` and `imv`. When used in conjunction with `set -o vi` an alias like `alias mv='imv --pass-through'` is a nice convenience with a Vim flavor. :)

Comment: The Batchy plugin from Martijn is pretty great imo

Comment: The [Fern](https://github.com/lambdalisue/fern.vim) plugin has the possibility to rename files based on the modification of a path buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The [Fern](https://github.com/lambdalisue/fern.vim) plugin has the possibility to rename files based on modification made on a Vim buffer.

1. Open the folder that contains the files that you want to rename: `:Fern path_to_folder`
2. Select the files you want to rename using the Fern action mark (`a` `mark` or `m`)
3. Select the action rename (`a` `rename`)
4. A buffer with the path selected is created
5. Modify the created buffer according to your need
6. Save the buffer (`:w`)
7. The files are renamed accordingly

Remark: If you want to mark all file of the folder you can use the mark-children (from the fern-mapping-mark-children.vim plugin) the folder root (the first item) (`a` `mark-children`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I really like my [batchy.vim](https://github.com/arp242/batchy.vim) tool, but of course I would say that as I wrote it

The main feature is that it's really simple and "obvious" to use it, which is important because I don't do batch renames very often. Every time I wanted to do batch renames I always had to figure out how to use $tool_I_choose_last_time; which included a few of batchy.vim's predecessors I had in my vimrc.

---

The README has more expansive docs, but to use it in brief, run `:Batchy`, which populates the current buffer with a list of files in the current directory, or run it from a shell alias:

```
alias batchy='vim +":Batchy echo" +"setl noswapfile buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide nowrap"'
```

This gives you a list of files in three columns:

```
ftplugin         ←  ftplugin         │  d  0.0K  Thu 2021-06-17 00:44:20
plugin           ←  plugin           │  d  0.0K  Thu 2021-06-17 00:50:21
LICENSE          ←  LICENSE          │  f  1.1K  Thu 2021-06-17 00:21:12
README.markdown  ←  README.markdown  │  f  2.3K  Thu 2021-06-17 00:45:46
```

Everything after the `│` is a comment and lists the file type, size, and
modification date. You can put anything you want there when editing. Note this is U+2502 ("box drawings light vertical") and not the regular `|` (U+007C, vertical line).

Now, let's say you modify the buffer to prefix every file with `xx-`:

```
xx-ftplugin         ←  ftplugin         │  d  0.0K  Thu 2021-06-17 00:44:20
xx-plugin           ←  plugin           │  d  0.0K  Thu 2021-06-17 00:50:21
xx-LICENSE          ←  LICENSE          │  f  1.1K  Thu 2021-06-17 00:21:12
xx-README.markdown  ←  README.markdown  │  f  2.3K  Thu 2021-06-17 00:45:46
```

Run `:Batchy` again and it will replace the buffer with a shell script:

```
mv -n 'ftplugin'         'xx-ftplugin'         # d  0.0K  Thu 2021-06-17 00:44:20
mv -n 'plugin'           'xx-plugin'           # d  0.0K  Thu 2021-06-17 00:51:16
mv -n 'LICENSE'          'xx-LICENSE'          # f  1.1K  Thu 2021-06-17 00:21:12
mv -n 'README.markdown'  'xx-README.markdown'  # f  2.5K  Thu 2021-06-17 00:51:06
```

*Nothing gets run automatically*. Write it to a file or use `:%!sh` to run it.

---

The nice thing about reversing the "dst src" order is that it's easier to edit things with standard Vim commands:

```
:%s/^/prefix-/    add a prefix
:%s/^prefix-//    remove a prefix

:%s/ /-suffix/    add a suffix
:%s/-suffix //    remove a suffix

:%s/word/NEW/     replace word; because only the first match is
                  replaced this leaves the source filename alone.
```

If it would keep the src dst order all of the above would require a lot more complex patterns.

Keeping the original filename in there is convenient as it's a bit clearer, and it also allows you to reorder things if you want; I was never quite comfterable with tools that depend on line numbers/order.

Simply delete a line if you want to leave that file alone.